# how can I exclude parts of a shaded jar in Play!'s lib folder

Tags: java, scala, playframework

I need to use a 3rd party shaded jar in my Play! (2.2.3) app via the unmanaged dependency mechanism by placing it in the lib folder. However, this jar contains an incompatible older version of jackson (2.0.4) causing a `NoSuchMethodError` when Play does JSON conversions.

How can I force Play! to use its own (2.3.2) version of of Jackson instead of the one in this jar?

Comment: A JAR is just a ZIP file, why don't unzip the unmanaged dependency JAR, delete the Jackson JAR and zip it again?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the "Conflict resolution" section of this the play framework documentation [`here`](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.4/dependency)

> But there is an exception. When a core dependency of Play framework itself is involved in a conflict, the version available in $PLAY/framework/lib is preferred
>
> Sometimes you want to force a specific dependency version, either to override a core dependency or to choose another revision that the latest version available.

So to resolve your problem, you can specify the force option on any dependency in the dependencies.yml file:

```
# Application dependencies
    
require:
    - play 1.2
    - com.google.guava -> guava r07:
        transitive: false
    - commons-lang 3.0:
        force: true
```

Comment: That is for play 1.x. Dependencies in Play 2.x are completely different.